# What does force of pressure mean

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, classical-mechanics

A chain hangs on the thread and touches the surface of table by its lower end. Show  that after the thread had burn through the force exerted on the table by the falling part of the chain at any moment is twice as great as the force of pressure exerted by the part already resting on the table
**what does force of pressure means in this question**

Comment: That is a very question... Sounds like a poorly worded task. Would you mind showing the exact formulation (is it in English?)?

Comment: As a chain is made of links, there may be only one link in contact with the table (the bottom one) while the others are falling... so how does their mass contribute?

Comment: @Sanjay It is a question from **PROBLEMS IN GENERAL PHYSICS** by **I.E.IRODOV**.

Comment: How to approach this question I could not understand what question is saying